# IIRF Rewrite Condintion and Rewrite Rules

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iirf

I'm re-writing a Coldfusion site in PHP.  I just started learning about IIRF and how it works with IIS 6.  For testing purposes, I want a rewrite condition that looks for specific .cfm files and redirects them to corresponding .php files.  Then, after the redirect, I want to remove the file extention .php. I'm doing this to try to help with indexing and preserve a high SEO ranking.  I'm OK at understanding regex, but no expert, so how would I write this in my .ini file?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're just being casual in your terminology, but it sounds like you may be confusing URL rewriting with redirecting.

It sounds like you want a user who is requesting `path/page.cfm` to be *redirected* to `path/page`, which will be your new canonical URL.  To accomplish this, you'll want a rule like:

```
RewriteRule (*).cfm $1 [R=301,L]
```

In addition, you would like the new request for `path/page` to be processed by the file at `path/page.php`.  To accomplish this, you'll want a rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (*) $1.php [L]
```